# cx_Freeze .app crashes when external import is used (mac OS monterey)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem freezing my tkinter application. As long as I don't import an external library the frozen app works. If I import a module like pandas the app crashes with no error messages. My OS is macOS monterey, I also tried on a windows machine and the same problem happens. Here's an example code:

````
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd # it only works after building if this line is ommited 


class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Welcome to My_App")
        self.geometry('350x200')


app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with the conda environment and there is somehow a clash between the conda env and cx_Freeze. It was solved when I created a pyenv.